# Python How to find a word but not exactly the same between two list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to compare two list where the first list is the word I want to find, and the other list contains string I need to find

I tried using regex, but regex can't hash the list.

The data

```py
split_data = ['Java Programmer',
              'Candidate must possess at least Bachelor Degree in Engineering (Computer/Telecommunication), Computer Science/Information Technology or equivalent.',
              'similar job','Software Developer','Data Scientist']   
related_str = ['related','recommended','similar']
```

This one works only on 'similar'

```py
index_target = [i for i, item in enumerate(split_data) if re.search(re.compile("^similar"),item)]
```

I tried this

```
for item in enumerate(split_data):
        if item in related_str:
            index_target.extend(item)
```

I expected the output to be

```
['similar job']
```

but it returns

```
[]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't seem to need regex. Just use plain `in` with list comprehension:

```
[sdata for rstr in related_str for sdata in split_data if rstr in sdata]
# ['similar job']
```

Comment: Gives duplicate output if the string matches multiple strings e.g. "'similar recommended job" -> ['similar recommended job','similar recommended job'] .Consider the use of any()

Answer (score 1):

Using `re.search`

**Ex:**

```
import re

split_data = ['Java Programmer',
              'Candidate must possess at least Bachelor Degree in Engineering (Computer/Telecommunication), Computer Science/Information Technology or equivalent.',
              'similar job','Software Developer','Data Scientist']   
related_str = ['related','recommended','similar']

toSearch = re.compile("(" + "|".join(related_str) + ")")
for i in split_data:
    if toSearch.search(i):
        print(i)

#OR
print([i for i in split_data if toSearch.search(i)])
```

**Output:**

```
similar job
['similar job']
```

Answer (score 0):

Potentially with some prepossessing of the raw_strings

```
import re
word_set = set(related_str)
[raw_string for raw_string in split_data
        if any(word in word_set for word in re.split('[^a-zA-Z]', raw_string.lower()))]
# ['similar job']
```